# QPSQL driver not found

Tags: база-данных, qt, postgresql, macos, psql

Совсем недавно начал пользоваться маком. Сейчас пишу проект на Qt и хочу использовать postgresql.
Скачал psql с помощью homebrew. Вывод подключения к бд через qt :

```
QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QPSQL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы использовать драйвер PostgreSQL с помощью Qt, вам нужно убедиться, что вы установили библиотеку драйвера PostgreSQL и загрузили ее в вашу программу Qt.

Чтобы установить библиотеку драйвера PostgreSQL, можно воспользоваться пакетным менеджером, например, Homebrew:

```
brew install libpq
```

После установки библиотеки нужно подключить ее к проекту Qt. Для этого вы можете использовать файл проекта .pro:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lpq
```

Также нужно убедиться, что драйвер PostgreSQL подключен к Qt. Это можно сделать с помощью макроса QT_USE_QSQLITE:

```
QT += sql
QT += sql-psql
```

После этого вы сможете использовать драйвер PostgreSQL с помощью Qt, указав имя драйвера QPSQL при создании объекта QSqlDatabase.